# Python 3.6 - Tkinter - Treeview no muestra fuente en color

Tags: python, tkinter, fuentes

Tengo una aplicación desarrollada en Tkinter en la que muestro un elemento Treeview con información. A algunas filas le asigno una etiqueta para cambiar el color de la fuente:

```
self.tree_view.tag_configure('green', foreground='#088A08')
```

Y cuando añado las filas les asigno la etiqueta:

```
self.tree_view.insert("", tk.END, text=ind+1, values=values, tags=(tag,))
```

El problema es que en mi PC se visualizan bien los colores pero cuando ejecuto la aplicación en otro PC no se ven.

Es posible que sea por algún archivo de fuentes o librerías de Windows?

Comment: Hola Alfredo, ¿te pasa en dos sistemas con el mismo sistema operativo o el sistema operativo es distinto? ¿Misma versión de Python  en ambos casos?

Comment: El sistema operativo es el mismo, la versión de Python no lo se.